# Having an issue with my visualforce override

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

I've recently created an override within Salesforce for the default "New" button on the Opportunity tab using the following:

Everything is working perfectly, but when I created a new custom button on the contact object and replaced the original "New" one from the related list section which is the only place my company wants Opps created, this still fires and displays the message.

What am I missing so that my override is not triggered by the "New Opportunity" button I've replaced the original "New" button in the Opportunity Related Lists section of the Contact page layout?

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
<apex:includeLightning />
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageMessage summary="Create Opportunity from Contact record" severity="info"
     strength="3" />
    <apex:pageMessages />           
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: When you implement an overide of a standard action that is a global override. Anywhere you are able to make a new opportunity will be overwritten with your visualforce page

Comment: Hmm...Okay. Is there a way to include an exception to my override though?

Comment: Not exactly. It's overridden or it's not, you can't have exceptions.

Comment: Even when using a 'nooverride'? That way I could have the Contact object as an exception to the override?

Comment: If there's no override then you'll be using the standard new page handled by salesforce, but you won't be preventing users from creating new opportunities from other places on the platform